# Can I ask questions about features and functionalities of the Stack Exchange Android App here?

Tags: support, meta

Is the "Stack Apps" Stack Exchange site the appropriate site to ask questions about features and functionalities of the Stack Exchange Android App?

It says 'Apps' in the title, sure, but you'll forgive me for not assuming anything about anything when it comes to the Stack Exchange platform. There are a LOT of things that are named this, but are what I like to refer to as "Stack Hack Attack Traps". That's where the most maniacal of moderators lie in wait, for the next idiot to wander in and be so foolish as to ask a question that should be legitimate if the names of some of the Stack Exchange sites were named with words that reflected whatever it was the moderators dictate it was.

So, I don't want to upset anyone and force them to have to discipline me for being one of the stupids. If the Apps room IS where app questions are asked, I'll be pretty gleeful!!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, StackExchange is no longer developing the Android, or iOS, app.  So you won't get any suggestions for improvement accepted.

To ask how to use it, the Android Users site is for help with Android apps generally.  There should be help there.  Alternatively, the main SE Meta site, but you may be less successful there.

This site is for people developing their own apps to interact with SE.

Comment: Man, I do enjoy the rare moments when I call a game perfectly! Thanks for that!!